# Разбор заголовка пакета(C++, sockets)

Tags: сокеты, сниффер, c++

Есть генератор UDP пакетов и сниффер . Когда сниффер ловит нужный пакет , сохраняю его содержимое в файл.
Что сохраняется в файл : **E  >o  ЂдАЁ (ХЗі•E  *    Ђ  АЁ (ХЗі•/Ё/Є Я^Hello World!!**
Подскажите пожалуйста как перевести всю информацию до Hello World!! ?
ps : в wireshark по нажатию на любой из символов(например на 'E' или '*') до хелловорлд отображает ТТЛ , порты , айпи итд.
Как мне в файл вывести также как в wiresharke ?:>

Comment: Ну к примеру если у вас есть код генератора UDP пакетов то посмотрите какие данные там в пакет пишутся. Ну а дальше пишете утилитку которая будет разбирать ваши пакеты и писать как вам надо.
Эти каракули как бы бинарные данные которые содержат в себе информацию порта, айпи, размера строки.

Comment: Берёте соответствующие rfc (udp, tcp, ip, если он ловится -- я просто не знаю) и расшифровываете).

Comment: Вот [здесь](http://www.tenouk.com/cnlinuxsockettutorials.html) много полезной информации.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, сохраняйте не сами символы, а их коды в hex-виде. Так уже будет нагляднее.
Во-вторых, открывайте стандарты на соответствующие протоколы и смотрите что по каким смещениям лежит. Парсите пакет и пишете все в наглядном виде в файл и/или на экран